# Can I make git-svn more like git?

Tags: git, git-svn

Is it possible (or desirable?!) to set up `git svn` to behave more like `git`? For example, instead of writing

```
git svn dcommit
```

why can't I just write

```
git push
```

Similarly, instead of

```
git svn rebase
```

why not just

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

git and svn are philosophically different, and pushing/pulling is one of the key differences.

While I could argue that what you are proposing is fundamentally wrong (and you even suggest that in your question), you could accomplish your goal with aliases and a bit of mental re-wiring.

These aren't perfect, but might work for you or give you some ideas.

```
#file: .git/config
# assumes your svn-remote is called svn
alias.co = git config svn-remote.svn.url > /dev/null && git svn rebase || git pull --rebase
alias.ci = git config svn-remote.svn.url > /dev/null && git svn dcommit || git push
```

Answer (score 2):

git is different than svn. git-svn is a extension to allow people to use git with svn.

One collision is the checkout action, which kind of checkout do you mean? "svn checkout" or "git checkout" or a "git svn clone".

Another is "commit", local "git commit", remote "svn commit" :P

That's not to say, they couldn't try to hide more of the differences, by looking at the config.

Comment: Huh? There's no such thing as "git svn checkout". Anyway, I guess it's true that the abstraction would be too leaky to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

To use standard Git workflow and commands when working with Subversion repository, you may use SubGit (http://subgit.com/) instead of git-svn.

SubGit works faster, doesn't require you to keep history linear with "git rebase" and lets you push and pull with any Git client.

Disclaimer: I'm a SubGit developer.